# I don't get the number of input in this program if i put the number of input

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;

public class dotcom{

    public static void main(String Args[]){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input :");
        int i = s.nextInt();
        ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println(mylist.size());

        for(int x=1 ; x<=i ; x++){    \\ if I put I=2 then it would take only 1 input instead of 2 
            String sc=s.nextLine();
            mylist.add(sc);
        }
        System.out.println(mylist.size());
    }
}
```

pls help me

I am trying to learn array list

Comment: Please read above line.

Comment: just add one "s.nextLine();" before for loop.